# How to list items in combobox?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a `UserForm` with an empty `ComboBox` to be populated with a list of formulated (basic concatenate) text for user to select. I got the below code but failed.

```
Private Sub specList_change()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ListSpec As String
    'Clear whatever in listbox
    Me.specList.Clear
    Me.lineText = ""
    Me.partText = ""
    'Get none empty data from P6:Pxx
    i = 5
    Do
        DoEvents
        i = i + 1
        ListSpec = Sheets("SPEC CHART").Range("P" & i)
        'Add data into the listbox till all data in SPEC CHART worksheet is empty
        If Len(ListSpec) <> 0 Then specList.AddItem (ListSpec)
    Loop Until ListSpec = ""
End Sub
```

Appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UserForm_Initialize` event instead.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim r As Range, lr As Long
    With Sheets("SPEC CHART")
        lr = .Range("P" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lr > 5 Then
            Set r = .Range("P6:P" & lr)
            Me.speclist.RowSource = r.Address(, , , True)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Aslo if the source is a Range, you can use `RowSource` property.
You can also use the `List` property like this:

```
Me.speclist.List = Application.Transpose(r)
```

That is in place of `me.speclist.RowSource = r.Address(, , , True)`. HTH.